# Are the properties in {...rest} being passed down to {routeProps} when passing props in react-router?

Tags: reactjs

I was going through this example of passing our own props given on the React Router website:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/render-func

```
function FadingRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={routeProps => (
        <FadeIn>
          <Component {...routeProps} />
        </FadeIn>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Q: is the {...rest} being passed down to  in order to pass the ...rest object to routeProps?

Thanx.
A.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `rest` won't be passed to `routeProps` so you need to merge them yourself when passing down to the `Component`:

```
<Component {...routeProps} {...rest} />
```

:)

Comment: Could you explain further. What is the utility of {....rest} in <Route {...rest} if its not being passed, i.e. I don't see {...rest} being used in anyway and if it isnt, how would I make use of it in <Route ... ?

Comment: Here `rest` is used  for one thing, namely for passing props down to `Route` component, so it can determine whether you can access a route or not. If in your case you need to pass them farther to `Component` then _just do it_ as I've shown before and you'll be fine :)